# How to restrict autocomplete to find places in specific city

Tags: google-places

How to restrict the Google's Places autocomplete to find places in specific city only, using HTTP requests. For example, New York?

Comment: see my answer here, hope it helps: stackoverflow.com/a/62294304/4324194

Answer (score 0):

You can set the location bias to the center of that city and a radius that approximates the boundaries of the city, but cannot guarantee that results will only be within those city limits. The Places API only supports restricting results to a specified country.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing

If it's a hard requirement to only display the results that fall within in your specified city, you can examine the Autocomplete response that is returned, run a Place Details request (specifying only Basic details fields) on each place_id that is returned, and only display the predictions whose locality or adminstrative_area_level_n matches the city name.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: which adminstrative_area_level is city? 1 2 3.. etc?
can I just restrict for it like: adminstrative_area_level_3 = Tel Aviv?